# How to store location information of different users from an android app to firebase real-time database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save the location information (Latitude & Longitude) of different users in the firebase real-time database. I have successfully done that for a single user but how to do it for each user who is using my app? I am developing using Java (not Kotlin) in the background so any help in this regard will be very helpful.

...

I just want to know that if we have two users simultaniously using my app, how do I track them using user IDs? Right now even if I am using 2 instances of my app, it is continuously replacing the data in the firebase database.

[Snapshot of my firebase Db is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlGYA.png)

Comment: This is a really broad topic, so it's unlikely we'll be able to help better than already done in these previous [questions on saving user data](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+store+information+for+user). If you tried this and ran into problems, edit your question (there's a link right under it) to include the [minimum, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Kindly see the snapshot. I just want the data to be saved there under different usernames.

Comment: I linked a search that has quite some questions that cover that already. Did you read those and try to apply it to your own problem? If so, can you edit your question to show the code of where you got stuck?